# Editing Gateway Errors

Tags: magento-1.7, authorize.net

How do you customize the Gateway Errors that pop up when a customer's credit card is declined.

Example would be "Payment transaction failed. Reason  Gateway error: An error occurred during processing. Please try again."

We're using Authorize.net if that makes a difference. To clarify, we aren't looking to get rid of them, just modify the language in them.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the file app/code/core/Mage/Paygate/Model/Authorizenet.php to local.  Then find this (line 1334):

```
protected function _wrapGatewayError($text)
{
    return Mage::helper('paygate')->__('Gateway error: %s', $text);
}
```

and replace with this:

```
 protected function _wrapGatewayError($text)
{
    if($text == 'This transaction has been declined.') {
        $text = 'Custom message here.';
    }       
    return Mage::helper('paygate')->__('Gateway error: %s', $text);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I will leave this here for the future in case if someone runs into this.

The `_wrapGatewayError()` method already uses a helper to output the message, so why not just translate the message?

1. **Create (or edit)** your localization/translation file in `app/design/frontend/{package_name}/{theme_name}/locale/en_US/translate.csv`. You can check the active `package_name` and `theme_name` in System / Configuration / Design (under 'General').
2. **Add the messages** you are changing to that file in this format: "Old text - message you want to change", "New message".

In your case, it will be something like this:
"Payment transaction failed. Reason Gateway error: An error occurred during processing. Please try again.", "Your custom message"

**How it works:** whenever a helper is used to output the "Payment translation failed. ...", the system will find the translation file (translate.csv) and will change the message to your custom one.

**Please don't modify core files**. It creates a mess, interferes with patches, and makes debugging harder. You can extend them if you need to. See [Overriding Magento blocks, models, helpers and controllers](https://inchoo.net/magento/overriding-magento-blocks-models-helpers-and-controllers/)